# Network error handling in silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight-3.0, tcp, network-programming, tcpclient, tcplistener

We are writting silverlight3 application, which use Tcp connction.
Our project use client server architecture.
Client part is silverlight application, and server part is winform application.
We use TcpClient and TcpListner for connection.
We can handle following errors:
1. user shut down
2. users network cable unpluging
3. server shut down

But we can't handle servers network cable unpluging on user level(for server we handle it with NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged event).
How we can do it?
And is there other network which we must handle for application correct work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We added ping to our application and with it can handle all network problems.